# Javascript map add value to exist key

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Hello I've got problem with map in js,
I've got list of orders in form like this=>

```js
const ORDERS = [
  {
    orderId:1,
    category:"sport",
    amount:350,
    time:'2019-12-15T19:23:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    orderId:2,
    category:"sport",
    amount:350,
    time:'2019-12-15T19:21:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    orderId:3,
    category:"garden",
    amount:120,
    time:'2019-12-15T19:25:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    orderId:4,
    category:"sport",
    amount:250,
    time:'2019-12-15T19:23:30.000Z'
  }
]
```

I want to create map key based on unique category and amount and map value is a array with times.
For example reffered to above order list:
key: {category:'Sport',amount:350} and value: [{'2019-12-15T19:23:30.000Z'},{'2019-12-15T19:21:30.000Z'}],
key:{category:'Sport',amount:250} and value: [{'2019-12-15T19:23:30.000Z'}]
key:{category:'garden',amount:120} and value: [{'2019-12-15T19:25:30.000Z'}]

But when I iterate in for loop then always create new key with this same specific like before. I want to add only new value(time) to exist key.

```
export const duplicateOrders = (orders = []) => {
  let orderMap = new Map();

  for(let i = 0 ; i<= orders.length-1; i++){
    let key = [orders[i].category,orders[i].amount];
    let value = orders[i].time;
    if(!orderMap.has(key)){
      orderMap.set(key,value);
    } else{
      let old = orderMap.get(key);
      orderMap.set(key,(old + value));
    }
}
```

these are my scribbles without desirable result

Comment: Objects as Map keys are using their identity, not some custom structural equality.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple if issues.

1. Like mentioned in the comments: it checks for identity, not equality. So two arrays with the same content are not the same.
2. When you set the value, you don't push the other time to the list of values for the key but you concatenate strings. Probably also not what you want.

What you could do here, simply make a string from category and amount like so

```
const key = `${orders[i].category}_${orders[i].amount}`
```

later on, when you set the value, make sure that you work with arrays, like so:

```
if (!orderMap.has(key)) {
      // no order found, add this one
      orderMap.set(key, [value]);
    } else{
      // order found, add the date
      orderMap.get(key).push(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an object (like an array) as the key to the Map entry, then you need to use that object again (or a pointer to it) in order to retrieve its value. (in essence, the memory address is your key, so only that memory address will grant you access to that Map entry)

By creating the "same" array again (i.e. the same values in each element of the array), the new array will not have the same memory address as the old one and so it will not work to retrieve your old Map entry. (object comparisons by default compare memory addresses).

e.g.:

```js
const arr1 = ['sport','350'];
const arr2 = ['sport', '350'];

console.log(arr1 == arr2); //false

const arr1Copy = arr1; //a pointer to arr1

console.log(arr1 == arr1Copy); //true
```

So for your example to work, convert your array to a string:

```js
const duplicateOrders = (orders = []) => {
  let orderMap = new Map();

  for(let i = 0 ; i < orders.length; i++){
    let key = `[${orders[i].category},${orders[i].amount}]`;
    let value = orders[i].time;
    //console.log(key, value);
    if(!orderMap.has(key)){
      orderMap.set(key,value);
    } else{
      let old = orderMap.get(key);
      orderMap.set(key,(old + ", " +  value));
    }
  }
  return orderMap;
}

console.log(duplicateOrders(ORDERS));
```

```html
<script id="setUpData">

const ORDERS = [
  {
    orderId:1,
    category:"sport",
    amount:350,
    time:'2019-12-15T19:23:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    orderId:2,
    category:"sport",
    amount:350,
    time:'2019-12-15T19:21:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    orderId:3,
    category:"garden",
    amount:120,
    time:'2019-12-15T19:25:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    orderId:4,
    category:"sport",
    amount:250,
    time:'2019-12-15T19:23:30.000Z'
  }
]

</script>
```

Output (for some reason this sandbox/snippet console doesn't display it):

[image]

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(mapObject.entries()))`  stack snippets console.log output intercepts and stringifies objects before output.  stringify(Map) outputs {}

Answer (score 0):

Uses a two layer object map for keeping track of two keys.  Unwraps using Object.values and flatMap.
Note: Other answers of creating a generated concatenated key should be sufficient, unless you have some problems with key serialization causing conflicts.

```js
const collector = os=>Object.values(os.reduce(
  (acc,{category:key, amount, time})=>{
   const hasTime = acc?.[key]?.[amount]?.time;
   if( typeof hasTime === 'undefined' )
     acc[key] = {...acc[key], [amount]: {key, amount, time: [time] }};
   else acc[key][amount].time.push(time);
   return acc;
},{}
)).flatMap(x=>Object.values(x));
const ORDERS = [
  {
    orderId:1,
    category:"sport",
    amount:350,
    time:'2019-12-15T19:23:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    orderId:2,
    category:"sport",
    amount:350,
    time:'2019-12-15T19:21:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    orderId:3,
    category:"garden",
    amount:120,
    time:'2019-12-15T19:25:30.000Z'
  },
  {
    orderId:4,
    category:"sport",
    amount:250,
    time:'2019-12-15T19:23:30.000Z'
  }
]
console.log(
collector(ORDERS)
);
```